cheapest way to describe a git hash
I need to get the same result of git describe <hash> for remote repository.
For example, given the hash d96edbcf, I want to get something like v0.54.0-1-gd96edbcf
I need to this for multiple repos, so I'm looking for an efficient way to do this without having to check out the whole repo each time.
Fetching the hash does't work as then git describe <hash> says No names found, cannot describe anything

If you just need metadata analysis, fetch just the metadata. That'll cut out almost all the fetch traffic. Add --bare --filter=tree:0 to your clone, and if you know a tip that will have that hash add --single-branch $tip to skip stuff you know is irrelevant.

I'd start with git ls-remote. If the commit in question is tagged or if it's at the head of a branch you can easily find it without cloning. Example:
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git | grep "^192c1d0"
192c1d01fb1dac29d06b60c521846da7971f3960        refs/tags/3.2.0^{}

Unfortunately if the commit is not at a ref there is no generic way to describe it without cloning. Either you use GitHub/GitLab APIs or clone at least something. You can clone as little as possible — only commits, not blobs, no checkout.
If you know a branch to which the commit belongs you can clone a single branch:
$ git clone --bare --branch=master --filter=blob:none --single-branch https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git
$ cd mimedecode.git
$ git describe 192c1d0          
3.2.0
$ git describe bf6c8b1
3.2.0-3-gbf6c8b1
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf mimedecode.git

If you don't know a branch you need clone more:
$ git clone --bare --filter=blob:none https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git
$ cd mimedecode.git
$ git describe 192c1d0          
3.2.0
$ git describe bf6c8b1
3.2.0-3-gbf6c8b1
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf mimedecode.git


thanks for the recommendations. That reduced the size considerably. If I know the commit should be at least after a certain tag, is there any way to to reduce this further? Maybe get the history starting on that point?

@pablochacin git clone --branch allows tags. git clone --bare --branch=3.2.0 --filter=blob:none --single-branch https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode.git works for me.

that's useful, but I also know that the commit is after a certain tag (in my case, It's a release) and I want to skip the many thousands of previous commits.

@pablochacin You can add --depth but you have to guess it, there is no way to calculate. You can add --shallow-since with a date. You can try --shallow-exclude with your commit to cut at exactly the commit. See the docs.

@pablochacin Oops, sorry. --shallow-exclude= cannot be a hash. It requires a reference. BTW I did an experiment and found that --filter=tree:0 is slightly more efficient than blob:none.
